# How can I use a Global Object in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a resource and I need to use the attributes of that Object independently of the view, I think I need to declare the object in application controller, but I'm not sure.

Basically, I need the app can change the style using a resource, but all the change need to apply on the all views

I created a model with differents attributes like header_color, main_color, footer_color, etc. but when a put the code in the header, example:

```
<div class="header" style="background: <%= @style.header_color %>">
```

Ok, this works in the views of the same resource but not in diferent views, and I get a nil error

Comment: You want to change styles dynamically using CSS I'm assuming. How do you intend to supply and store these styles? What have you tried so far? What did the code look like?

Comment: Missing where `@style` is declared, what view your erb is in, what your controller looks like, what action(s) was the view working for, what action(s) was it not.